# Критический критерий

Tags: этимология

Недавно в контрольной по мат. статистике прочитала выражение "Критический критерий". Я пометила его как тавтологию, но потом задумалась: ведь эти слова только внешне похоже. "Критический" в статистике означает "пороговый", "крайний". А "критерий" - "мерило", "признак".

Вот и возник у меня вопрос, а являются ли два этих слова родственными? Или это случайное внешнее сходство?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, "критический критерий" отнюдь не является абсолютной тавтологией из-за обилия разных толкований и у существительного, и у прилагательного. Хотя, согласен, в контексте конкретной математической дисциплины вызлядит неоправданным плеоназмом.

Во-вторых, по сути вопроса. Разумется, в греческом все связано. И еще - "кризис" сюда же. 
Но применительно к русскому языку возникает теминологическая неопределенность: cчитать ли родство в языке-источнике основанием для родства слов, заимствованных разными путями? Однозначного ответа нет. Поэтому предлагаю ограничиться греческим (максимум - латинским).

В основе - греческий морф со значением "суждние", "различение".

КРИТЕРИЙ
или критериум, лат. criterium, от греч. kriterion, от krino, сужу. Признак для распознания истины, которым руководствуется разум в составлении о ней суждения.

кри́тика
(гр. kritike искусство разбирать, судить)
1) разбор, обсуждение чего-л. с целью дать оценку, выявить недостатки;
2) отрицательное суждение о чём-л., указание недостатков.

И кстати:
кризис
кри́зис через нем. Krisis (с 1519 г.; см. Шульц–Баслер 1, 405) из лат. crisis от греч. κρίσις "решение, исход"; κρίνω "различаю, сужу".

Comment: Спасибо, интересно! Кстати, значение "критический" в статистике не связано с понятием "критика", по крайней мере, напрямую. Уж скорее сближается в "кризисом".  
Впрочем, и в обычном языке есть этот смысл: "больной находился в критическом состоянии" - т.е. в крайнем, пороговом, на грани. В кризисе, в общем. Правда, в статистике "кризисность" стертая, без драматизма.

Comment: Так оно и по жизни не связано. Но отрицать происхожение "критический" от "критика" вряд ли кто решится.

Answer (score 0):

Сложновато понять, что такое "критический критерий". Критическим (пороговым) может быть значение чего-то, например, того же критерия. Есть ли уверенность в том, что термин *критический критерий* имеет право на существование? Я в гугле не нашла такого термина, но встретилось, к примеру, "критическое значение критерия Фишера". Подозреваю, что это все-таки может быть ошибочное словосочетание, в котором нарушена логика и имеется ввиду "критическое значение критерия". Тавтологии нет, судя по всему, но звучит странновато.

Comment: Разумеется, это невозможное сочетание! Математически это ошибка. Но меня интересует лингвистический аспект: как связаны (или не связаны) эти два слова?

Comment: Да, очевидно, связаны, хотя значения слов очень разные. Интересный случай. Греческий морф оказался плодотворным.